# Getting error as illegal invocation in jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery ,I am apparently trying to call a c-sharp function from javascript using ajax and jquery ,and I also want to pass some parameters while calling the c-sharp function ..
   This is how I trying to do the same:

```
var _data = {

    '_mStart': document.getElementById("St_Period"),
    '_mEnd': document.getElementById("En_Period")
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "maps.aspx/myFunc",
    data: _data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert("success!")
    }

});​
```

And here is my webmethod in aspx.cs

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static void myFunc(DateTime? _mStart, DateTime? _mEnd)
    {

        try
        {
            //string st = St_Period.Value.ToString();
            //string end = En_Period.Value.ToString();
            SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("server=SWAPPS_LAP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=moogle;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveresultSets=true");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into MEDIA_BOOKING(ST_PERIOD,END_PERIOD,ENTERED_BY,ENTERED_ON) values(@st,@end,@by,@on)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st", _mStart);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", _mEnd);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@by", Session["login"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@on", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

When I run the code I get an error like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery.js:7601
jQuery.extend.param.add jquery.js:7601
buildParams jquery.js:7658
buildParams jquery.js:7653
buildParams jquery.js:7653
jQuery.extend.param jquery.js:7621
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7467
savebook maps.aspx:398
onclick
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the elements values not, the DOM elements.

```
var _data = {
    '_mStart': document.getElementById("St_Period").value,
    '_mEnd': document.getElementById("En_Period").value
};​
```

**Instead of:**

```
var _data = {
    '_mStart': document.getElementById("St_Period"),
    '_mEnd': document.getElementById("En_Period")
};​
```

Comment: yes I have corrected it ,but now I am getting internal server error 500

Comment: @Snedden27. O.k. so the problem is now solved. You got other issue in server code. You should debug it and see where is the problem, if you can't find it, please ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `St_Period` and `En_Period` are html `input` elements you would need to add the values to the data object not the elements e.g.:

```
 var _data = {

            '_mStart': document.getElementById("St_Period").value,
            '_mEnd': document.getElementById("En_Period").value
        };
```

Comment: they are as hidden field value,anyway I added the .value extension but now the error is this

POST http://localhost:50060/moogle/maps.aspx/myFunc 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:8102
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery.js:8102
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7580
savebook maps.aspx:398
onclick

Comment: @Snedden27: The error is now on the server. Looking at your code it may be an SQL error as you have commented out the addition of the `@by` parameter. Can you debug the request via Visual Studio?

Comment: Yeah it calls the myFunc code when I debugg in visual basic ,I think the json string is not in the correct format or something like that,wait I would ask a new question to clarify things